# Converting list of lists of tuples to list of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this old random list:

```
old_list = [[(0, 1), (0, 2)], [(8, 4), (3, 7)]]
```

And I want to convert the tuples to lists like this :

```
>>> new_list = [[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[8, 4], [3, 7]]]
```

I tried the below with a list comprehension, but apparently, it is wrong:

```
new_list = [list (y for y in x) for x in old_list]
```

Answer (score 4):

You need nested list comprehensions to create a nested result. The tuples that need to be converted to lists are at the second level down.

```
new_list = [[list(tup) for tup in level1] for level1 in old_list]
```

Comment: LOL, how do you keep beating me by 12 seconds?

Comment: You don't get to 688k by being a slowpoke :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
new_list = [[list(x) for x in y] for y in old_list]
```

which produces:

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[8, 4], [3, 7]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what you do :) 
`list(np.array(old_list))`

Comment: Hello there! I recommend sharing your output which allows other users who probably won't run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to array with numpy module or you can simply just convert to list with list() method. Look for example:

[Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyTBF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic solution and there is no user of the extra list. I am updating the old_list :

```
for i in range(0, len(old_list)):
    for j in range(0, len(old_list[i])):
        old_list[i][j] = list(old_list[i][j])
print old_list
```

O/P

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 2]], [[8, 4], [3, 7]]]
```